# Chef: Jenkins cookbook recipe for enabling security

Tags: security, jenkins, chef-infra, rsa, cookbook

I am currently using the Chef supermarket [Jenkins cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/jenkins) to deploy an instance of Jenkins. I am attempting to enable security in my configuration of the jenkins instance in the _master_war_.rb recipe file. [Code to enable security and create a user using an RSA key](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/jenkins-chefci/blob/e1b82e679074e96de5d6e668b0f10549c48b58d1/recipes/_jenkins_chef_user.rb) is below:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'net/ssh'

unless node.run_state[:jenkins_private_key]

 # defaults to /etc/chef-jenkins-api.key
 key_path = node['jenkins_chefci']['jenkins_private_key_path']

 begin
   Chef::Log.info 'Trying to read private key from ' + key_path + ' for the chef user in jenkins'
   key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read(key_path)
   Chef::Log.info 'Successfully read existing private key'
 rescue
   key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new 2048
   Chef::Log.info 'Generating new key pair for the chef user in jenkins in ' + key_path

   file key_path do
     content key.to_pem
     mode 0500
     sensitive true
   end
 end

 public_key = [key.ssh_type, [key.to_blob].pack('m0'), 'auto-generated key'].join(' ')

 # Create the Jenkins user with the public key
 jenkins_user 'chef' do
   id 'chef@' + Chef::Config[:node_name]
   full_name 'Chef Client'
   public_keys [public_key]
 end

 # Set the private key on the Jenkins executor
 node.run_state[:jenkins_private_key] = key.to_pem

end
```

When I attempt to apply this recipe in a run list on a managed node, I receive the following error:

```
NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

The stacktrace indicates that the error is related to this particular line of code from my recipe file:

```
>>  key_path = node['jenkins_chefci']['jenkins_private_key_path']
```

I have seen this error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass), quite a bit online, however have not been able to narrow down the root cause in my recipe. Could I be missing something in my recipe file? I'm wondering if the root cause of the error could be related to these couple lines:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'net/ssh'
```

Comment: You can't just copy attributes from other cookbooks ;-) Replace `node['jenkins_chefci']['jenkins_private_key_path']` with something valid. I recommend getting familiar with Chef using a bit an easier project. The jenkins cookbook is pretty tough.

Comment: Trial by fire :D I would like to take my time on something more simple, however for work I must use the Jenkins cookbook. So I understand per [this resource](https://www.coveros.com/chef-undefined-method-for-nilclass/), ['jenkins_private_key_path'] is a sub attribute of ['jenkins_chefci']. In the code I'm using above, key_path is equal to this value. I'm not exactly sure what this line of code does? I think I'll be able to resolve this error once I can understand exactly what is happening in this line of code. As I know you understand this particular code intimately, do you have any info?

Comment: It's an attribute, filled with the value defined [here](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/jenkins-chefci/blob/e1b82e679074e96de5d6e668b0f10549c48b58d1/attributes/jenkins.rb#L5). Just replace it with a valid path..

Comment: Jenkins is not a trial by fire, it's a trial by "if he was innocent he wouldn't have sunk to the bottom of the lake". It really doesn't like being automated.